# What is the operation flow in this code? C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm studying for my final exam and I have the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* f(int *i) {
    (*i)--;
    return i;
}

void main() {

    int a;
    int b = 2019;

    a = (*f(&b))--;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

When I print the values, `a = 2018` and `b = 2017`. Why is that? Why `a` get 2018 and after that `b` gets `--`?

Comment: Because the last operation is a post-decrement? If you want a language-lawyer answer you should probably pick either C or C++.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `x++`, and `++x`?

Answer (score 5):

A pointer to `b` is passed in `f()` under the parameter `int *i`. `f` dereferences this pointer to `b` and decrements `b` by one using this code

```
(*i)--
```

So `b` starts as `2019`, it goes through `f` where it is decremented to `2018`.

`f()` also returns a pointer to an `int`, which in this case points to the address of `b`. So when this call happens

`a = (*f(&b))--;`

`f(&b)` returns a pointer to `b` after decrementing it

`a = (*(&b))--;`

The expression `*(&b)` is evaluated to deference `&b` i.e. get the value of `b` which is 2018 at this point, this is assigned to `a` which is why `a` is 2018.

Now, what does `x--` mean? It means `x = x-1`, so this translates to

`(*(&b)) = (*(&b))-1`

so `b` goes to 2017 in this case.

Comment: You mean `a = (*&b)--` or just `a = b--` I think - f(&b) returns &b - but yes.

Comment: thanks to whoever edited my answer, it's 3am and my formatting was a mess

Comment: `f(&b)` does nor return `b` after decrementing it.   It returns `&b` after decrementing `b`.

Comment: `b` is **not** passed by reference. The **address** of `b` is passed to `f`. `g(int&)` takes a reference; `f(int*)` does not.

Comment: NO, BAD, and WRONG, Variable `b` is NOT passed by reference, it's a pointer yo `b` which gets passed to `f` and it is passed by value. Next, `f(&b)` does NOT return `b`, it returns a pointer to `b`, Next, `(*b)` does NOT make any sense, as `b` is not a pointer. If this expression was equivalent to ANYTHING in the exaple code, you could simply replace it there – but if you actually do, the code would either NOT compile or would crash due to FORBIDDEN modifying memory at the addres 2018.

Comment: It may not be a C++ `int&` reference, but it is passed-by-reference in the sense the original value in b can be modified.

Comment: @CiaPan I've updated my answer. While you're right that it wasn't pass-by-reference, what I meant was the functional aspect of holding a reference to the input variable instead of just a value, you are correct and I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@mrMan
Well brother if you look closely at the statement a = (*f(&b))--; there is a post decrement happening here. This (*f(&b)) is a pointer function which means this holds a reference and not a value so as soon as return statement in function executed a is assigned a value of 2018 as it got decremented in the function above but now (*f(&b)) this right here holds a reference to value 2018 which got changed but has address of b so when (*f(&b))-- this happens it actually decreases the value of b further more.
Hope your question got cleared. Happy coding!!!!!!!!!! :)